# Epub library for C++

Tags: c++, qt, epub

Is there any library in C++ for creating Epub files, I need to use it with Qt.

My program can export html & css, but I don't know how to convert that to an Epub.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://projects.kde.org/projects/calligra/repository/revisions/master/entry/filters/words/epub/). This depends on a lot of KDE libs and calligra libs, but it's usable.

Comment: Take a look at Sigil and see how they do it: http://code.google.com/p/sigil/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from my googling efforts it appears that most of it is hand written and their isnt a globally accepted SDK. i found a nice tutorial for you which walks you through making epub files. and i did see some other links about using it with QT. maybe someone knows of a good open source project thats somewhere?

[epub tutorial](http://www.jedisaber.com/eBooks/formatsource.shtml)

Comment: Looking at this tutorial it seems creating epub is rather simple task given html & css export done.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've got the HTML and CSS, you're most of the way there; what remains is the content.opf file, which basically lists all the files in the epub document and the overall metadata (author, publisher, ISBN, etc); and the table of contents. epub 2.0.1 uses the toc.ncx file as a table of contents--it's basically an xml document. epub 3.0 uses the toc.xhtml, which is much more intuitive--it's essentially an ordered list in a nav element. You can do either epub 2.0.1 or epub 3.0; there's enough backwards compatibility built in that older devices will be able to read an epub 3.0 file--as long as you include both a toc.ncx and a toc.xhtml.

You may have to tinker with your CSS; epub doesn't support everything, and the device manufacturers all seem to interpret things differently; it's very "browser wars"-ish.

I find the IDPF's epub spec is the best place to go for formatting info. Here's the relevant bits:

- [content.opf](http://www.idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-publications.html#sec-package-elem)
- [toc.xhtml](http://www.idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-contentdocs.html#sec-xhtml-nav)
- [toc.ncx](http://www.idpf.org/epub/20/spec/OPF_2.0_latest.htm#Section2.4.1)